# Finding best players in a tournament with a probabilistic comparison function

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, stochastic-processes

I am currently facing the following problem in my research and I have no clue how to tackle this kind of question.

### The problem

Imagine you have a tournament with $n$ players $P=\{p_1,...,p_n\}$. My goal is to determine one of the best players in my tournament.

I do have a comparison function $f: P x P\to \{0,1\}$ that can tell me which of two given players is better, i.e. $f(p_1,p_2)=1$ iff player two is better than player one and $f(p_1,p_2)=0$ iff player one is better than player two. You can think of $f$ as the $<$ relation.

The kicker is that my comparison function $f$ has an error, meaning that it will give me the correct result of my comparison with a probability $p>0.5$. Calculating $f$ will take some time and thus I want to find a good player for my tournament with the least amount of queries. My current approach is to compare all players with each other which gives me a total amount of $b \in O(n^2)$ comparison calls. I then chose the player $p_i$, which "won" the most comparisons.

### Edit:

Please be aware that my comparison function will give me the same result for a call $f(p_i,p_j)$ no matter how often I call it. So the probability that the result is correct is $p$, but the function itself is deterministic. My example below is a bit misleading. However, each comparison call is only done once so this won't be a problem.

### Key questions

1. What is the probability that the chosen player is the best player?
2. What is the probability that the chosen player is in the top k percent?

### My thoughts

I think that question one might be easier to calculate as my best player will win all comparisons if $p=1$ and I can deduce the probability that $k$ comparisons were correct. However, I am stuck at the point at which I have to calculate the probability that it in fact is the player that "won" the most comparisons as others might be evaluated incorrectly.

My dream is to get a formula that allows me to calculate the desired probabilities for different $p,n$, and budget $b$.

### Simulation

I wrote a small simulation in Python which revealed some interesting facts about the influence of $p$. In my example, the tournament players are represented as numbers $0,...,63$. The function $f$ is the standard $<$ relation with a given probability. In the plot below I have plotted the mean position (y-axis) that was selected as the best individual for different $p$ (x-axis). You can find the source code below.

[image: Plot showing the mean position for different p and tournament size 64]

```
import random
import numpy as np
from itertools import combinations
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = [], []

n = 64 # How many players
nums = np.arange(n).tolist() # Player strengths
count = 1000 # The amount of tests (O(n^2)) combinations that should be made

for p in tqdm(np.arange(0, 1, 0.01)):
    x.append(p)

    def compare(a, b):
        r = random.random()
        if r <= p:
            return a < b
        else:
            return a >= b

    def tournament():
        scores = [0] * n
        for a, b in combinations(nums, 2):
            result = compare(a, b)
            if result:
                scores[b] += 1
            else:
                scores[a] += 1

        best = max(nums, key=lambda x: scores[x])
        return best

    vals = []

    for _ in range(count):
        vals.append(tournament())

    y.append(np.mean(vals))

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

Comment: There will be a balance between the probability of having the correct answer and the number of queries. So the question could be how to get `x%` assurance for the least number of queries.

Comment: are there any constraints on the "better" relation? for example, does it define a total order on $P$?

Comment: @user125932 I assume that the "correct" relation defines a total order on the set of players. So you can assume without loss of generality that $p_1<p_2<...<p_n$.

Comment: @Royi This is another interesting question that arises from my question. In fact, it would be a better question to ask for my specific use case.

Comment: I have a formula for the case of a knock-out format. This would be $b \in O(\log n)$. But your question with all comparisons sounds much more complicated.

Comment: I am very interested in your findings. Feel free to share your formula with us/me. I can post it as an edit to my question or you can propose it as in answer if you like. Your ideas might inspire me and others.

Comment: Looks difficult. Similar problem: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267054/for-a-round-robin-tournament-what-is-the-favorites-least-favorite-size

Comment: @leonbloy The problem is in fact related. However, in their case all players except the best player have the same probability of winning a game in the Round Robin Tournament. In my case the probabilities that $p_i$ wins the game highly depends on $i$ assuming a total ordering $p_1 < p_2 < ... < p_n$. I doubt that increasing the number of players so that it tends to infinity would reveal the best player.

Comment: I do not understand the budget $b$. What is it you are budgeting? If you do all pairwise comparisons the number (b?) is fixed at $n(n-1)/2$.

Comment: @gg Yes for now it is fixed at $n(n-1)/2$, but I can imagine that you can achieve accuracies that are close to the best achievable accuracy with fewer queries, and in these cases, I want to minimize $b$ as well, i.e. use a different strategy than comparing every player to every other.

Comment: One more question: The errors in your comparison are really independent? So if $f(1,2)$ and $f(2,3)$ both check out as true, this will not affect the error of $f(1,3)$, which will still be correct (only) with probability $p$?

Comment: @gg In my use case, my comparison function is modeled by a neural network (binary classification) which will have relatively low accuracy. This makes it more likely that these probabilities are related to each other. Nevertheless, I think it is easier if we assume that the probabilities are stochastically independent as it makes the calculation easier.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but an equivalent (and hopefully neater) reformulation of the problem.

We have $n$ players indexed from $1$ to $n$. When players $i,j$ ($i<j$) are matched, the probability that $i$ wins is a constant $p>1/2$ (no draws). The play a round-robin tournament.

What is the probability that player $1$ (the strongest one) is the (only) winner?

More in general: What is the probability that player $1$ is among the $k$ best scores?

Answer (score 1):

The score of player $p_i$ is roughly normal with mean $p(i-1)+(1-p)(n-1-i)$ and constant variance $(n-1)p(1-p)$.  Integrate the pdf of the top one multiplied by the cdfs of all the others.  That won't have a nice formula but might have a nice approximation.  With a gap of $2p-1$ between players' means and standard deviation of $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, the odds of the top player winning could be $O((2p-1)/\sqrt{np(1-p)})$.  Probabilities $p=1-k/ n$ for $k=O(1)$ might be the transition region where the top player's chances falls from 1.  Conversely, $p=(1/2)+k/\sqrt n$ might be the region where the weakest players' chances drop from $1/n$ to much less.
There is a small error in that cross-correlation between any two comes from a single comparison.
With a budget $b$, the means and variances are both scaled down in proportion to $b$, so the spreads overlap more.
Simulations using the normal distribution approximation suggest the chance of number-one winning is
$$\frac1{1+\left(\frac{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}{4p-2}\right)}$$
or, if you do $c{n\choose2}$ of the comparisons with $0\lt c\lt 1$,
$$\frac1{1+\left(\frac{\sqrt{np(1-p)/c}}{4p-2}\right)}$$

Comment: I do not understand the statement about the budget and the scaling. If you budget you will have not a fully balanced round-robin tournament and your first sentence about the means does not seem to be true anymore?

Comment: One way to budget is to compare $p_i$ with $p_{i+k}$ for all $i$, for a range of $k$. That keeps the symmetry.  You are right if the symmetry is lost.

Answer (score 0):

In the following I suggest a framework where all relevant probabilities can be calculated - in theory. In practice the combinatorial explosion of possibilities will require additional heuristics and short cuts. But all these can be addressed in this framework.

### Framework

To ensure that all relevant information can be processed, it is best to work on the set of all permutations. Every possible configuration of player strengths is captured by a permutation of order $n$. E.g. for $n=3$ the permutation $(2,3,1)$ means player 2 is worst player 1 is best and 3 is in-between. The unknown permutation describing the true strengths is called $\pi_*$.

A probability measure on permutations can be interpreted as $P(\pi) = P(\pi=\pi_*)$, i.e. giving the probability that $\pi$ is the true order of player strengths. From these basic probabilities all others can be derived. For example the probability of "Player $i$ is best" is given by the probability $P(A)$ where $A$ is the set of all permutations with player $i$ at the n-th (i.e. best) position or $A=\{\pi\mid \pi(n)=i\}$. It can be calculated as
$$ P(i \text{ is best}) = \sum_{\pi\in A}P(\pi).$$

Probabilities for other subsets of interest, such as "$i$ is among k-best", can be derived in the same fashion by adding up certain atomic probabilities.

### Comparisons

Comparisons allow to access information about the true permutation. Due to the uncertainty of the comparisons, they have to be described as probabilities. Let $A(i,j)$ be the set of all permutations where $i$ is before $j$ and $\bar{A}(i,j)$ its complement. A comparison $f(p_i,p_j)$ which evaluates TRUE (with probability $p$), can then be interpreted as a condition on the measure $P$:
$$ P(A(i,j)) = p \text{ and accordingly } P(\bar{A}(i,j)) = 1-p.$$

If $f(p_i,p_j)$ evaluates FALSE the conditions are reversed:
$$ P(A(i,j)) = 1-p \text{ and } P(\bar{A}(i,j)) = p. $$

Performing several comparisons $c_1,\ldots,c_M$ just leads to more, i.e. $M$, conditions.

Example:

Take $n=4$ and the two comparisons between 1 and 2 as well as between 3 and 4.
Denote by $A_{00}, A_{01}, A_{10}, A_{11}$ the partition of all permutations where $A_{00} = A(1,2)\cap A(3,4)$ and $A_{10} = \bar{A}(1,2)\cap A(3,4)$ and so on. If $f(p_1,p_2)=TRUE$ and $f(p_3,p_4)=FALSE$ then $P(A_{00})=P(A_{11})=p(1-p)$, $P(A_{01})=p^2$ and $P(A_{10})=(1 - p)^2.$

Note that all conditions are linear constraints on the atomic probabilities.

### Unique compatible measure

Since all constraints are linear, the atomic probabilities $q_1=P(\pi_1), \ldots, q_{n!}=P(\pi_{n!})$ compatible with the comparisons can be found by solving a system of linear equations together with the probability constraints $q_N\geq 0$ and $\sum q_N=1$. Depending on the number of comparisons this system may be underdetermined, and will not have a unique solution. The example above is a case in point. Each group $A_{xx}$ contains 6 permutations. But there is no information about the probabilities within each set. A standard trick which enforces uniqueness and is consistent with our ignorance about probabilities within each group is to choose among all measures compatible with the constraints the measure with maximal entropy.

### Numeric example

Entropy maximisation with linear constraints can be solved by convex solvers. The following examples were calculated using CVRX interface and the ECOS solver in R.

Parameters were $n=4$ and all 6 round-robin comparisons "allcomp" and "inccomp" three comparisons $1<2$, $2<3$, $3<4$. The table shows the probabilities of $i=1,2,3,4$ being the best assuming all comparisons evaluate TRUE.

For $p=0.9$:

```
|   |   allcomp|   inccomp|
|:--|---------:|---------:|
|1  | 0.0402612| 0.0345995|
|2  | 0.0404158| 0.0535842|
|3  | 0.0983847| 0.1008493|
|4  | 0.8209382| 0.8109670|
```

For $p=0.6$

```
|   |   allcomp|   inccomp|
|:--|---------:|---------:|
|1  | 0.1752993| 0.1753445|
|2  | 0.2063212| 0.2115260|
|3  | 0.2614596| 0.2640440|
|4  | 0.3569198| 0.3490855|
```

### Further considerations

Better than static approaches where comparisons are defined in advance and are independent of the outcomes, seem dynamic approaches to me. With these later comparisons are determined by earlier outcomes. This makes greedy and divide-and-conquer approaches possible.